# How to provide command arguments as an array?

Tags: bash, command, arguments

I'm trying to test if an archive has all its files. All I need to do is a simple unzip and then make. The shell keeps trying to interpret arguments like `-aoq` as a program. Other errors exist as well, but I'll spare readers each and every way *not* to do it. Here are some of the failed attempts:

***Failed***:

```
RESULT=$(unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/")
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]]; then ... fi;

RESULT=$(unzip (-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/"))
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]]; then ... fi;

RESULT=$(unzip ("-aoq" "cryptopp.zip" "-d" "$TMP/cryptopp-zip/"))
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]]; then ... fi;

RESULT=$(unzip "-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d $TMP/cryptopp563-zip/")
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]]; then ... fi;

RESULT=$(unzip "{-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/"}")
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]]; then ... fi;

RESULT=$(unzip "(-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/")")
if [[ "$RESULT" -eq "0" ]]; then
...
```

If I see one more question and answer that says "just use parenthesis", "just use quotes" or "just use curly braces" I think I am going to scream...

How do I call `unzip` with arguments so that Bash does not try to interpret the arguments as commands?

---

Here's a couple of the more comical error messages:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open {-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d /tmp/cryptopp563-zip/}, {-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d
/tmp/cryptopp563-zip/}.zip or {-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d /tmp/cryptopp563-zip/}.ZIP.


unzip:  cannot find or open (-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d /tmp/cryptopp563-zip/), (-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d
/tmp/cryptopp563-zip/).zip or (-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d /tmp/cryptopp563-zip/).ZIP.
```

---

Here are a few questions/answers that did not work for me. I'm fairly certain I have visited U&L.SE, Stack Overflow and Super User multiple times.

- [Bash: convert command line arguments into array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12711786)
- [Passing arrays as parameters in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063347)
- [how to pass an array argument to the bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17232526)
- [Passing array values to command args](https://superuser.com/q/1093086)

Comment: Is the text output of `unzip` really going to be `0`, or did you mean to instead inspect `$?` for the exit code of `unzip`?

Comment: @thrig - originally I was trying to call like `if [[ ( $(unzip ...) -eq "0") ]]; then ... fi`. But I broke it out into two parts when trying to make it work.

Comment: Then you broke it wrong as it will compare the command's output.

Comment: What's the problem with your very first attempt?  It looks like your best shot.

Comment: @JuliePelletier - *What's the problem with your very first attemp..."* - The shell was trying to execute the program `-aoq`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier - *"Then you broke it wrong as it will compare the command's output...."* - that's a step in the right direction. Once I get the shell to execute `unzip` with its arguments, I can move onto return values.

Comment: @jww:  I just tested your first command (`RESULT=$(unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/")`) and it works perfectly.  Of course they're is nothing in `$RESULT` since the command does no output but it does extract the files to the expected location.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and clarify what you are trying to achieve? Like Julie, I can't tell what you're trying to do here. What are the outputs of the zip command? Are you simply trying to test if the unzip command was successful? That doesn't mean you're not missing files. Do you mean you just want to check if the archive can be extracted?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had to abandon this task. The task is driven from the Makefile, and the recipe performs a clean before zipping. Our test file was running this task and cleaning wipes our "test result" file. The expedient this to do was *not* automatically test zipping. Instead, we will manually test it.

Answer (score 5):

The first one:

```
RESULT=$(unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/")
```

should run `unzip` just fine, and drop its *output* to the variable `RESULT`. However, `unzip` doesn't print much in its standard output (well, unless with `unzip -l`), so I think you actually want the return value. Which can be found in `$?` after the assignment and command substitution, or just after running the program as normal:

```
unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/"
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ] ; then echo ok ; fi
```

(And yes, you could just `if unzip ... ; then ...`.)

You don't really have an array there, though, just a bunch of normal parameters to the command. This would make an array, print its length and pass it as arguments to `unzip`:

```
A=(-aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/")
echo ${#A[@]}
unzip "${A[@]}"   # note the quotes
```

Comment: Or just `if unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/"; then echo ok; fi`

Comment: Or even just `unzip -aoq cryptopp563.zip -d "$TMP/cryptopp563-zip/" && echo OK` as long as we're shortening things :)